# JQuery restart setInterval

Tags: jquery, restart, setinterval

Sorry to be a bore but having trouble restarting a setInterval with a toggle function.  I get to stop it - when needed, but I cannot get it to restart when the toggle "closes"

Here is my code

Set the setInterval

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval( function() { $('.holder').load('board.php'); }, 5000 );
```

Stop on toggle - BUT want it to start on the "reverse toggle"

```
$('.readmore').live('click',function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
    clearInterval(auto_refresh);
}, function() {
    var auto_refresh = setInterval( function() { $('.holder').load('board.php'); }, 5000 );
});
```

Help much appreciated, as is prob. very simple just I've never beed good at putting functions "within functions"

Comment: i presume your code isn't working because you're passing 2 functions into the `live()` function, what is your intention there? `live()` only binds 1 function...

Comment: @davin "what is your intention there?" - as per my Q I want to stop and start the setInterval based on the toggle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.readmore').live('click',function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');

    if(!auto_refresh ) {
        auto_refresh = setInterval( function() { $('.holder').load('board.php'); }, 5000 );
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(auto_refresh);
        auto_refresh = null;
    }
});
```

Or probably even better, use the state of the element to decide:

```
$('.readmore').live('click',function() {
    var $elem = $(this).next();

    if( $elem.is(':visible') ) {
        $elem.slideUp('slow');
        clearInterval(auto_refresh);
    }
    else {
        $elem.slideDown('slow');
        auto_refresh = setInterval( function() { $('.holder').load('board.php'); }, 5000 );

    }
});
```

Comment: OK, but just a quick look is that the "right" way round? if(auto_refresh) ... then I want to stop if not then I want to start - will give it a try anyhow - thanks

Comment: Got it to work thanks the "toggle" I am using is "reversed ie closed top show not show to close" if that makes any sense Thanks a lot