# how to restart setinterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
Line_Baslat();
setInterval(function(){ moveLeft(); Line_Baslat(); },4000);  

function Line_Tekrar () {
    $("#dv_line").animate({width:"0%"},0);
};
function Line_Baslat () {
    $("#dv_line").animate({width:"100%"},4000);
};
function refseh () {
    setInterval(update,4000);
};
$("#prev").click(function(){
    moveLeft();
    refresh();
});     
$("#next").click(function(){
    moveRight();
    refresh();
});
```

Comment: Please **describe** your problem.

Comment: This could be something worth reading going by your title. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758750/jquery-restart-setinterval?rq=1

Comment: let me google that for you:
https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+restart+setinterval

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` function returns ID of that interval, which you can use to cancel it. For example in your case

```
Line_Baslat();

var timeout;
function refresh () {
    if (timeout) {
        clearInterval(timeout);
    }

    timeout = setInterval(function(){ moveLeft(); Line_Baslat(); },4000); 
}; 

function Line_Tekrar () {
    $("#dv_line").animate({width:"0%"},0);
};
function Line_Baslat () {
    $("#dv_line").animate({width:"100%"},4000);
};
$("#prev").click(function(){
    moveLeft();
    refresh();
});     
$("#next").click(function(){
    moveRight();
    refresh();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing your `setInterval` body in another function, like this:

```
//doStuff variables.
var a = 0;
function doStuff(){
    //interval body
}

var interval;
interval = setInterval(function(){
doStuff(); //Call Interval Body
},timeout);

clearInterval(interval); //clear interval

//reset interval to call body function
interval = setInterval(function(){
doStuff(); //Call Interval Body
},timeout);
```

This allows you to restart/reset the interval.